# Call another epic inside one epic RXJS

Tags: javascript, react-redux, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm quite new to RXJS and development in general. I started working with rxjs recently and I found myself stuck with the following issue and I would appreciate some help/ guidance and some explanation please.

```
    export const updateSomethingEpic1 = (action$) =>
 action$
    .ofType('UPDATE_SOMETHING')
    .switchMap(({ result }: { result }) =>
      //SOME API CALL
        .map(({ response }) => updateSomethingSuccess(response)) 

         **make call to second epic**

        .catch(err => updateSomethingError(err)),
    );


      //My second epic

        export const updateSomethingEpic2 = (action$) =>
 action$
    .ofType('UPDATE_SOMETHING2')
    .switchMap(({ result }: { result }) =>
      //SOME API CALL
        .map(({ response }) => updateSomethingSuccess2(response))
        .catch(err => updateSomethingError2(err)),
    );
```

My question is how would I make a call to my second epic after my first epic has called the api and made a successful request. Want to make a call in the first epic after `updateSomethingSuccess` action, which adds response to the store and then call the second api afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Just do return an action.
Code from your sample

```
.map(({ response }) => updateSomethingSuccess(response) **<--- make call to second epic**)
```

use

```
.map(({ response }) => updateSomethingSuccess(response) )
```

where **updateSomethingSuccess(response)** is action creator like following

```
function updateSomethingSuccess(response) {
   return { type: 'UPDATE_SOMETHING2', payload: response}; // HERE
}
```

Then your epic 2 with ofType UPDATE_SOMETHING2 will be performed.

It's dead simple. You have to modify for your needs

Comment: my `updateSomethingSuccess ` already returns something else, like `function updateSomethingSuccess(response) {
   return { type: 'UPDATED_SUCCESSFULY', payload: response}; 
}`

Comment: my updateSomethingSuccess already returns something else, like function updateSomethingSuccess(response) { return { type: 'UPDATED_SUCCESSFULY', payload: response}; }, so this example wouldn't work right?

Comment: @jayd Make sure you have second epic combined. Check function combineEpics() in your rootEpic.

Comment: In the rootEpic they are combined. But how would I trigger the other epic without changing the action creater of updateSomethingSuccess of the first epic